# Making a server ping pong tool in batch

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I've currently made this but there is a unexpected error in the for loop.

Please help.

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 1F
TITLE (Ash's Script) Server Ping Pong

rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ECHO Started %time% %date% > X:\Scripts\ServerPing.txt

rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i in (X:\Scripts\ComputerLists\ServerList.csv) DO (
    PING %%i -n 1 -w 3
    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
        ECHO %%i ONLINE %time%>> X:\Scripts\ServerPing.txt 
    ) ELSE ( 
        ECHO %%i OFFLINE %time%>> X:\scripts\ServerPing.txt
    )
)

rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is that last echo correct? You're specifying `scripts` directory in lowercase, but in all other instances it's uppercase

Comment: @omgmog Windows isn't case sensitive

Comment: What type of unexpected error you get? Really an error or only an unexpected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is always true.

Use this instead:

```
if not errorlevel 1
```

Also change the redirection on the echo to files:

```
>>X:\Scripts\ServerPing.txt ECHO %%i ONLINE %time%
```

This eliminates a problem when the last character is a number (of a stream)

Another issue is that `%time%` is evaluated when the loop starts - to get a dynamic time in the log then enable delayed expansion and use `!time!` instead of `%time%`

Comment: Additional to `IF ERRORLEVEL 0 is always true.`. This is true as `IF ERRORLEVEL <n>` is true if errorlevel is `<n>` **or** above. (This is obvious to foxidrive, but perhaps not for everybody else)

Comment: Just to clarify jeb's comment: if the errorlevel returned is 50 then every errorlevel from 0 to 49 (and 50) will also test as true.